# C# how to get text value from PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, passwordbox

I have a `PasswordBox`. how can I get the input value from the `PasswordBox` after the input has been finished?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can get it from the `Password` property.

Answer (score 16):

You may extract it from `Password` property:

```
passwordBox.Password.ToString()
```

Comment: Surrounding your code with an explanation would seriously improve your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may not want to store the password in clear text in memory, from the msdn doc you should use SecurePassword in order to prevent that.

Example: `SecureString myPass = passwordBox.SecurePassword`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword

Answer (score 2):

If using a MaskedTextbox you can use the .text property.  For example:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( myMaskedTextbox.Text.Equals(PASSWORD) )
    {
        //do something
    }         

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use below code to get the length of PasswordBox

```
PasswordVariableName.Password.Length
```

It will certainly work on wp8

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name to your PasswordBox.

```xml
<PasswordBox Name="pwdBox"/>
```

Then you can access the password as plain text in the `.xaml.cs` file by using

```cs
var plainPassword = pwdBox.password;
```

I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493330/11327791) answer to a similar question where you get to know why you mustn't store this property value in any variable.

However, I found in documentation information about SecureString.

> When you get the Password property value, you expose the password as plain text in memory. To avoid this potential security risk, use the SecurePassword property to get the password as a SecureString.

[source of this quotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Correct me if I am wrong.

Greetings.
Jan.