# Get value from password text c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

This should be easy. I have seen multiple answers where this has been implemented with the way discribed below but for some reason i can't make it work for me.
 I have seen this for example which i think i understood it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327234/c-sharp-how-to-get-text-value-from-passwordbox), so for my (part of) code which is  `<input id="myPassword" type="password" />`i tried doing `myPassword.Text`which does not seem to work. 
Is there anything wrong with the above?

Comment: If you want to get it server side like `Request["password"]` you need to have a `name="password"` attribute / if you want to get it like `myPassword.Text` you have to have `runat="server"` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try any of these two. Easiest one is to make run at server.

```
 <input id="myPassword1" type="password" />
 <input id="myPassword2" type="password" runat ="server" />

 string pwd1 = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["myPassword1"]);
 string pwd2 = myPassword2.Value;
```

Comment: I have been able to do it with  `<input id="myPassword" type="password" name = "myPassword2" />` to take the value by using  `string password2 = Request.Form["myPassword2"];` so i don't think the run at sever is necessary

Answer (score 0):

myPassword.value (input elements have a value attribute, see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_password.asp)

If you are interested in server side access then try using

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" id="myPassword" />
```

Comment: What i want is like i am taking the value from a regular textbox in VS (`username1.Text`), to take the value from a type = ''password'' textbox. How can this be done?