# MVVM Binding Password

Tags: mvvm, binding, properties, passwords, passwordbox

I am re-factoring my application to implement the MVVM design and i came across my first problem...

Compiler won't let me bind to the Password property of the PasswordBox control.

Anyone have any ideas / suggestions.

Comment: Did you see this filthy, dirty hack?  http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

Comment: Hehe, thats one way of doing it :) I'll implement that, but maybe someone knows a different way. It does seem a bit hackish.

Comment: Oh.. you have to manually add Mode=TwoWay for it to work correctly.

Comment: @Will: how about putting it as an answer, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if there is a best practices version, but [here's a dirty filthy hack.](http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html)

Answer (score 0):

As it may be useful to others, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649830/1374267) shows another possible solution for this problem: the idea there is to pass the `PasswordBox` as a parameter to the command that handles the password validation so that its `Password` property is accessible from there...