# MVVM and password

Tags: mvvm

I'm using MVVM and the model has password field. From what I've found on web, when handling this password you must implement custom class for binding and use PasswordBox. I think this is overhead. Could you point me to a better way to using the add/edit usercontrols connected to a viewmodel with password?
Thank you

Comment: Everything is binding in MVVM.

Comment: Here's another SO question that deals with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/wpf-binding-to-the-passwordbox-in-mvvm-working-solution

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading through the top answer in Eric's link, and paying attention to the bit about not storing passwords as part of your Model anywhere for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way but not MVVM:

Xaml

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"
```

Xaml.cs

```
private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (viewModel != null && sender is PasswordBox)
        viewModel.DatabasePassword = ((PasswordBox) sender).Password;
}

private void Load()
{
    //Fills viewModel.DatabasePassword
    viewModel.ReadData();

    PasswordBox.Password = viewModel.DatabasePassword;
}
```