# Communicate from ViewModel to View

Tags: mvvm, properties, bind

I have a situation where I need to communicate from a ViewModel to View in case a change happens. The problem here is, the property I want to update does not have a DependencyProperty, and I have managed to get a way around to "bind (not really but..)" it from View to VM by breaking a little the MVVM pattern rules and simply adding in the code-behind an event:

```
(ViewModelSomething as DataContext).Password = pb.Password;
```

And this works. The problem is when I want to update this property on a View when a change happens in the VM. Is there even possible a such connection?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm. You probably won't like the accepted answer though...

Comment: why can a change to Password happen in a viewmodel without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the ViewModel

Comment: That is already implemented, the problem is the Property doesn't know where to bind its value, since there is no binding in the view

Comment: The problem is that PasswordBox.Password is not a dependency property, so it can't be bound...

Comment: I know that it can't be bound or else I would just use the standard binding... I'm asking if there is a way around.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `GetCredential()` method in your Login View and you can get the updated values from this method in your ViewModel.

Implementation will be like

**View.cs**

```
public Credential GetCredential()
    {
        var credential = new Credential()
        {
            Username = txtUserName.Text,
            Password = txtPassword.Password
        };
        return credential;
    }
```

You need a **Credential** class

```
 public class Credential
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

On Submit button Command Handler you can get values from your View

```
 Credential credential = View.GetCredential();
```