# RelayCommand<PasswordBox> CanExecute never runs on Windows 8.1 store but it does on WPF

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, mvvm-light

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 store app with C# and .NET Frameowork 4.5.1.

I'm trying to pass a `PasswordBox` as a parameter on a button `Command`. I've tested the following code on WPF and it works.

`MainViewModel` class:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand<PasswordBox> doLoginCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="UserName" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string UserNamePropertyName = "UserName";

    private string _userName = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the UserName property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _userName;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(UserNamePropertyName, ref _userName, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<PasswordBox> DoLoginCommand
    {
        get { return doLoginCommand; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ////if (IsInDesignMode)
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs "for real"
        ////}

        this.doLoginCommand = new RelayCommand<PasswordBox>((pb) => ExecuteDoLogin(pb), (pb) => CanDoLogin(pb));
        //this.doLoginCommand = new RelayCommand<PasswordBox>((pb) => ExecuteDoLogin(pb));
    }

    private void ExecuteDoLogin(object parameter)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = parameter as PasswordBox;
        Debug.WriteLine(_userName);
        Debug.WriteLine(passwordBox.Password);
    }

    private bool CanDoLogin(object parameter)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CanDoLogin");
        PasswordBox passwordBox = parameter as PasswordBox;
        return ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userName)) &&
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordBox.Password)));
    }
}
```

And its `View`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.W81.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject.W81"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="77*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="400" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="600">
            <TextBox
                x:Name="userName"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Width="247"
                Margin="10,10,10,5"/>
            <PasswordBox
                x:Name="userPassword"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="250"
                FontFamily="Global User Interface"
                Margin="10,5"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="loginButton"
                Content="Login"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Command="{Binding DoLoginCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=userPassword}"
                Margin="10,5" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

But on Windows 8.1 it doesn't work. The problem is that `loginButton` is always disabled.

I have removed `CanDoLogin` on `doLoginCommand` creation and I can get `_userName` and `userPassword.Password` values.

Any advice? Do you know why `loginButton` is always disabled?

Comment: You're *not* using MVVM if you're passing any UI element as an `ICommand` parameter... view models shouldn't know anything about the UI. You should probably take a look at the [How to bind to a PasswordBox in MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm) question too.

Comment: Yes, I know what I'm doing. I'm asking why this code doesn't work on Windows 8.1 Store.

Comment: *doesn't work* isn't a very good description of your problem... not a lot to go on.

Comment: 1. Type in user name textbox. 2. Type password in PasswordBox 3. Click back on username TextBox to change focus.  Can you click `loginButton` now? If not what part of `return ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userName)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordBox.Password)));` is failing?

Comment: @Sheridan Please, read my question carefully; the problem description is there: The problem is that `loginButton` is always disabled.

Comment: @NETscape I've added a log on `ConDoLogin` and it only runs on initilization, when I do `this.doLoginCommand = new RelayCommand<PasswordBox>((pb) => ExecuteDoLogin(pb), (pb) => CanDoLogin(pb));`.

Comment: @VansFannel should it be: `RelayCommand<Button> DoLoginCommand`?

Comment: @NETscape No, it's `RelayCommand<PasswordBox>`.

Answer (score 1):

Don´t you have to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the command then something changes? Haven´t done any WPF in a long time but in apps I always call RaiseCanExecuteChanged.

Is this case I would call RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the PasswordChanged event.