# WPF Relaycommand get passwordbox value

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have this Passwordbox with this trigger :

```
<PasswordBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChanged}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</PasswordBox>
```

How can I, in my RelayCommand, get the content of my PasswordBox?

This is my relay command :

```cs
PasswordChanged = new RelayCommand<object>(param => this.GoPasswordChanged());

private void GoPasswordChanged()
{      
}
```

Comment: just access the `PasswordBox.Password` property ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4649830/2819451

Comment: Nop, my relaycommand is in my viewmodel, I can't access directly to Passworxbox.password

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had just to change :

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChanged}" />
```

To :

```
 <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PasswordBoxInput}" />
```

And :

```
PasswordChanged = new RelayCommand<object>(param => this.GoPasswordChanged(param));

private void GoPasswordChanged(param)
        {

        }
```

To :

```
private void GoPasswordChanged(object param)
        {
            var passwordBox = param as PasswordBox;
            var password = passwordBox.Password;
        }
```

Comment: IMHO Bind your password as a property in the viewmodel. So you directly access from the viewmodel