# implementing a login view

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a login view in my WPF application.

I've developed a view for my login including the following code:

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Label>Username:</Label>
            <TextBox Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Username}"/>
            <Label>Password:</Label>
            <PasswordBox Height="25" Margin="0,20,0,0" Name="txtPassword"/>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10" TabIndex="99"
                Command="{Binding Path=LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtPassword, Path=Password}">Login</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

in my code side I have

```
public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; loginCmd.CanExecute(value); }
        }

        ICommand loginCmd = new PasswordCommand();
        public ICommand LoginCommand => loginCmd;

private class PasswordCommand : ICommand
        {
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
            private string username;

            public AuthenticatedClient AuthenticatedClient;

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                username = parameter as string;
                return true;// !string.IsNullOrEmpty(username);
            }

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(parameter as string);

                if (AuthenticatedClient == null)
                {
                    AuthenticatedClient = new AuthenticatedClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthEndpoint"],
                                                              username,
                                                              parameter as string,
                                                              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
                                                              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);
                }
}
```

I need the Password to be sent to my endpoint in order to authenticate the user but the value comes up is blank. How can I fix my code?

Comment: I cant see a password variable over here and its not passed to the AuthenticatedClient elsewhere....

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword?view=netframework-4.8, here is the reason... Binding Password exposes the password in memory. Use securepassword instead

Comment: For usage examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm this may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best answer I found in the Internet was saying:

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Label>Username:</Label>
            <TextBox Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Username}" Name="txtUsername"/>
            <Label>Password:</Label>
            <PasswordBox Height="25" Margin="0,-20,0,0" Name="txtPassword"
                         ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"  ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10" TabIndex="99" Height="25" Content="Login"
                Command="{Binding Path=LoginCommand}">
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

therefore we can bind the Password

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to the `Password` or `SecurePassword` property like this, but if you just want to be able to extract the password in clear text in your command, you could bind to the control itself:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    PasswordBox pb = parameter as PasswordBox;
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(pb.Password);

    //...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtPassword}">
```