# Is binding of UpdateSourceTrigger to a DependencyProperty possible?

Tags: wpf, updatesourcetrigger

i want to set UpdateSourceTrigger of the Binding of a PasswordBox to LostFocus or PropertyChanged dynamically.

Is there a way to bind UpdateSourceTrigger of a Binding to a DependencyProperty like this?

```
Password="{Binding Path=PasswordProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger={Binding UpdateSourceTriggerProperty}"
```

Kind Regards,
Andy

Comment: No. A Binding is not a DependencyObject, you can't bind its properties. You may perhaps use a DataTrigger to set the Password Binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of an existing binding in the way you're attempting because, as Clemens points out, it is not a dependency property. Normally, you'd be able to accomplish this by using a `Style` with `DataTrigger`s that replace the entire binding, but in this case you can't do that either because *`Password` is also not a dependency property*.

This later point is an intentional design choice on Microsoft's part:

> When you get the `Password` property value, you expose the password as plain text in memory. To avoid this potential security risk, use the `SecurePassword` property to get the password as a `SecureString`.

For more of an explanation you can take a look at this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493330/5086631) from the question [How to bind to a PasswordBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm).