# WPF, Caliburn Micro Binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have the following in LoginView:

```
<TextBox x:Name="username" />
<PasswordBox x:Name="password"/>
<Button x:Name="doLogin" Content="Login"/>
```

And the following in LoginViewModel:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
internal class LoginViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

    public bool CandoLogin()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password);
    }

    public void doLogin()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(username);
    }
}
```

Now when I enter username and password in their respective fields I expect the button to be enable but that's not happening.

Am I missing anything. Note, this is my first MVVM project and Caliburn also.

**UPDATE:**
The problem is with the `PasswordBox` otherwise all the binding is working fine. Here are different references for `PasswordBox` binding:

[MVVM PasswordBox Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm)

[Caliburn Micro PasswordBox Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631522/caliburn-micro-support-for-passwordbox)

Comment: You're not showing the code of the button

Comment: Thanks @KooKiz missed that.

Comment: Where is all you property change notify code?

Comment: Seem to remember view models needing to be public.

Comment: @IanRingrose those are automatically handle by `Fody.PropertyChangedBase`  and that's why the annotation `[ImplementPropertyChanged]`

Comment: @JackHughes changing `internal` to `public` didn't make any difference.

Comment: Is canDoLogin() being called  (set a breakpoint in it or add a trace.)

Comment: @IanRingrose, thanks for the continuos help, but it would be easier to help if you fully understand the essence of Calibur Micro and the MVVM. These are supposed to be automatically handled by Caliburn Micro.

Comment: Just basic debugging, Calibure (or something) should be calling CandoLongin() whenever the password/username is changed.   So is it being called?   If so does it return the correct result?    Is the databinding hookup working for username and password?

Comment: Looking at http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions there is a example very much like what you are doing, but calls to NotifyOfPropertyChange() are being made from the property set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84700/discussion-between-zulq-and-ian-ringrose).

Comment: Oh yeah password is different than your standard TextBox