# How can I databind to the plain-text value of a RichEditBox in UWP?

Tags: uwp, richeditbox

With a normal `TextBox` in UWP, you can databind to the `Text` property and easily get or set the value from a ViewModel. The [`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox) doesn't have a data-bindable `Text` property though; instead you have to use the [`ITextDocument` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument) exposed by the `Document` property and use various methods to get and set text.

How can I databind the plain text to something in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to data-bind the plain-text of a `RichEditBox` by using a custom [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/attached-properties-overview). This attached property handles the conversion between the rich text and the plain text of the document.

Here is an example XAML page, code-behind, and ViewModel showing the usage of the attached property:

#### XAML

Copy this as the content of a new page in your project

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <StackPanel Margin="30">
    <RichEditBox local:RichEditBoxExtension.PlainText="{Binding PlainText,
      Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="richedit"/>
    <Button Content="Bold selection" Click="MakeBold"/>
    <Button Content="Change plain text (view model)" Click="ChangeText"/>
    <Button Content="Change rich text (control property)" Click="ChangeRichText"/>
    <TextBlock Text="PlainText property is..." />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlainText, Mode=OneWay}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

#### Code behind

This assumes you're using the default `MainPage.xaml.cs`; change the constructor name as appropriate

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = model = new ViewModel();
  model.PlainText = "Hello, world";
}

private void ChangeText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  model.PlainText = "Here is some plain text";
}

private void ChangeRichText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  richedit.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, "Here is some rich text");
  var selection = richedit.Document.Selection;
  selection.StartPosition = 8;
  selection.EndPosition = 12;
  selection.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.Single;
  selection.MoveStart(TextRangeUnit.Word, 1);
  selection.Expand(TextRangeUnit.Word);
  selection.CharacterFormat.Weight = FontWeights.Bold.Weight;
}

private void MakeBold(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  richedit.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Weight = FontWeights.Bold.Weight;
}
```

#### ViewModel

Nothing special; just a single string property. You can put this in its own file, or paste it into the main code-behind file.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  string plainText;
  public string PlainText
  {
    get { return plainText; }
    set
    {
      plainText = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

So far, nothing special. The `RichEditBox` uses the attached property `RichEditBoxExtension.PlainText` and binds it to the ViewModel property `PlainText`. There is another `TextBlock` on the page to show the current value of the `PlainText` property, and a few buttons to manipulate the text.

The implementation of `RichEditBoxExtension.PlainText` is pretty straight-forward, but it takes a fair amount of code due to the dependency-property infrastructure and the need to avoid endless property updates (where changing the rich text triggers the plain text, which triggers the rich text which triggers the plain text, and so on and so on).

#### Attached property

This can be in its own file or again just pasted into the code-behind file.

```
public class RichEditBoxExtension
{
  // Standard attached property. It mimics the "Text" property of normal text boxes
  public static readonly DependencyProperty PlainTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PlainText", typeof(string),
    typeof(RichEditBoxExtension), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPlainTextChanged));

  // Standard DP infrastructure
  public static string GetPlainText(DependencyObject o)
  {
    return o.GetValue(PlainTextProperty) as string;
  }

  // Standard DP infrastructure
  public static void SetPlainText(DependencyObject o, string s)
  {
    o.SetValue(PlainTextProperty, s);
  }

  private static void OnPlainTextChanged(DependencyObject o, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var source = o as RichEditBox;
    if (o == null || e.NewValue == null)
      return;

    // This attaches an event handler for the TextChange event in the RichEditBox,
    // ensuring that we're made aware of any changes
    AttachRichEditBoxChangingHelper(o);

    // To avoid endless property updates, we make sure we only change the RichText's 
    // Document if the PlainText was modified (vs. if PlainText is responding to 
    // Document being modified)
    var state = GetState(o);
    switch (state)
    {
      case RichEditChangeState.Idle:
        var text = e.NewValue as string;
        SetState(o, RichEditChangeState.PlainTextChanged);
        source.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, text);
        break;

      case RichEditChangeState.RichTextChanged:
        SetState(o, RichEditChangeState.Idle);
        break;

      default:
        Debug.Assert(false, "Unknown state");
        SetState(o, RichEditChangeState.Idle);
        break;
    }
  }

  #region Glue

  // Trivial state machine to determine who last changed the text properties
  enum RichEditChangeState
  {
    Idle,
    RichTextChanged,
    PlainTextChanged,
    Unknown
  }

  // Helper class that just stores a state inside a textbox, determining
  // whether it is already being changed by code or not
  class RichEditChangeStateHelper
  {
    public RichEditChangeState State { get; set; }
  }

  // Private attached property (never seen in XAML or anywhere else) to attach
  // the state variable for us. Because this isn't used in XAML, we don't need
  // the normal GetXXX and SetXXX static methods.
  static readonly DependencyProperty RichEditChangeStateHelperProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RichEditChangeStateHelper",
    typeof(RichEditChangeStateHelper), typeof(RichEditBoxExtension), null);

  // Inject our state into the textbox, and also attach an event-handler
  // for the TextChanged event.
  static void AttachRichEditBoxChangingHelper(DependencyObject o)
  {
    if (o.GetValue(RichEditChangeStateHelperProperty) != null)
      return;

    var richEdit = o as RichEditBox;
    var helper = new RichEditChangeStateHelper();
    o.SetValue(RichEditChangeStateHelperProperty, helper);

    richEdit.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
      // To avoid re-entrancy, make sure we're not already changing
      var state = GetState(o);
      switch (state)
      {
        case RichEditChangeState.Idle:
          string text = null;
          richEdit.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out text);
          if (text != GetPlainText(o))
          {
            SetState(o, RichEditChangeState.RichTextChanged);
            o.SetValue(PlainTextProperty, text);
          }
          break;

        case RichEditChangeState.PlainTextChanged:
          SetState(o, RichEditChangeState.Idle);
          break;

        default:
          Debug.Assert(false, "Unknown state");
          SetState(o, RichEditChangeState.Idle);
          break;
      }
    };
  }

  // Helper to set the state managed by the textbox
  static void SetState(DependencyObject o, RichEditChangeState state)
  {
    (o.GetValue(RichEditChangeStateHelperProperty) 
      as RichEditChangeStateHelper).State = state;
  }

  // Helper to get the state managed by the textbox
  static RichEditChangeState GetState(DependencyObject o)
  {
    return (o.GetValue(RichEditChangeStateHelperProperty) 
      as RichEditChangeStateHelper).State;
  }
  #endregion
}
```

The attached property basically does two things, but there's a lot of boilerplate code and state machinery surrounding it:

1. When the `PlainText` attached property is changed, it updates the `RichEditBox` with the plain text using `source.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, text)`
2. When the `RichEditBox` text changes (including rich text changes), it updates the `PlainText` attached property using `richEdit.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out text)` and then `o.SetValue(PlainTextProperty, text)`.

Note that this basic approach can be used to data-bind other "derived" properties that you want to compute based off real data-bindable properties.

Comment: this attached property implementation works like a charm on Caliburn micro. (even though you mentioned its not related). I don't think I could implement anything like this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The checked answer is an amazing solution. However, my workaround is:

- Add a *Visibility="Collapsed"* TextBox
- Bind it to a string
- Add *TextChanged* event and its callback handler to the TextBox
- In the handler, *Document.SetText* the string value into RichEditBox

Comment: That works too (you'd need a corresponding event on the RTB to bind the other way).